# Measuring Program execution time

Tags: scripting, measurement

I would like to call a program from a script, (malwarebytes, chkdsk, A/V scan) and have the script keep track of how long the program ran.  Could someone point me in the direction of what I should be looking for to get this accomplished?

Comment: You mean like [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time)?

Answer (score 0):

On Unix/Linux, you can use the `time(1)` command for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command e.g.

```
time ls -lR
real    0m0.178s
user    0m0.034s
sys     0m0.104s
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're talking about a Windows environment:

> malwarebytes, chkdsk

There's a [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line) that covers multiple ways to accomplish your goal depending upon your OS version and tools available (PowerShell, notably).